# How to fix UTF-8 double encoded data on large MySQL database

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have approx 70 databases, each database contains 750+ tables (exact same structure), and lot of data stored but, the problem is only few databases set to `utf8` and others are `latin1`, so `latin1` database saved double encoded values like `æŽ¥è¿‘åˆå ±` for `接近初報`

So i want to convert all my databases to `utf8mb4` so it should save correct data, but this will obviously requires existing double encoded data to convert to `utf8mb4`

I have following sql query to convert data.

`UPDATE table SET col = IFNULL(CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(col USING latin1) USING binary) USING utf8), col )`

But the problem is my databases are very large and this will take lot of time to convert data to `utf8`. so is there any easy way to update data for whole database in one go or something else which is easy?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you use perl, php or python ?

Comment: Hi, @DanielE. yes, I am using PHP 7.2

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using **`utf8mb4` for Chinese**; some Chinese characters are not representable in MySQL's 3-byte `utf8`.

A slightly **shorter expression**:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)
```

**Which case?** see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases -- You probably need the 3rd of these:

- CHARACTER SET latin1, but have utf8 bytes in it; leave bytes alone while fixing charset:
  First, lets assume you have this declaration for tbl.col:

  `col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL`

Then, to convert the column without changing the bytes:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(111) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL;
```

Note: If you start with TEXT, use BLOB as the intermediate definition.  Since `ALTER` needs to know all the details (size, nullness, etc), it is quite messy to dynamically create the `ALTERs`.

- CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 with double-encoding:

  `UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);`
- CHARACTER SET latin1 with double-encoding: Do the 2-step ALTER, then fix the double-encoding.

**Going through the tables**:

```
SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE ", table_schema, ".", table_name, "
         SET ", column_name, " = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(", column_name, 
         " USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);")
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE character_set_name = 'latin1';
```

Then copy & paste the output.  (Or write a Stored Procedure to do the execute.)

Caveat:  The `SELECTs` may pick more tables/columns than it should.